# How to unit test controllers in Yii

Tags: testing, controller, yii

How's this done? Do I just prepare a `$_POST`/`$_GET`/`$_FILES` set and pass it to the controller? Or is there some more elegant way to test the Yii controllers?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Usually, unit testing is performed for models, helper, components, etc. So in other words, for something that implements `application business logic`.
For test application controllers, a commonly used process is `Functional Testing`.

More information on performing such tests can be found in the [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.functional).

In a nutshell, use some thing like Selenium, which opens some url in a web-browser and collects information after the test.

Another technique to test controllers described [over here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/8298-testing-controller/).

By the way, if it is difficult to have the logic implemented into your controller, look for the `Fat Model` approach in MVC pattern. [More information here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/30244-fat-models-or-fat-controllers/).

Comment: It isn't really that the controller logic is overly complicated. But to access some of the logged-in-only parts, I'd have to fake a session or something, I think. I'm not sure how to do that. I will check out the links you mention.

Comment: PS: I'm doing what the guy from the forum link is doing. But how do I 'log in' using this method, to access private parts of the webapp?

Comment: OP please fix the typo.. `documention` should be `documentation`.